# cmake can't find installed component using find_package (install COMPONENT != find_package COMPONENT ?)

Tags: cmake

I've been using cmake 3.2 for almost a year now, with good success.

I'm trying to install a 'headers' and 'library' component separately, and then use find_package to require each component.  The install works just fine using the custom target.  But, find_package fails when the COMPONENT keyword is added for the package/component I just installed.

```
    install(FILES
       include/sum.h
       ...
       include/sumvmtypes.h
       DESTINATION ${APP_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR}/sum
       COMPONENT headers
    )

    add_custom_target(install_headers
       COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=headers 
           -P "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake" )
```

I'm using the PackageConfigHelper to create the package configuration file for the project, and it has been working just fine.

```
configure_package_config_file(${PACKAGE_NAME}-config.cmake.in
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-config.cmake
   INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}
   PATH_VARS NEOS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIB_INSTALL_DIR INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR APP_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR )
```

I added the macro for checking for the components to the ...cmake.in file.

```
check_required_components(neo_sumlib)
```

As a debugging step, I made sure the <package>_FIND_COMPONENTS did include 'headers' at cmake configuration.  Even though it can find the <package>.cmake file without issue, the <package>_<comp>_FOUND is not set.

Here's my idea.  COMPONENTS for the install command is not the same as COMPONENTS for the find_package command.  Is it that COMPONENTS for the **find_package** is really looking for <package>_<component> library, not the component defined by the **install** ?

thanks
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

`find_package(Foo COMPONENTS A B C)` refers to libraries which have been packaged into the NAMESPACE Foo and would be linked like `Foo::A Foo::B ...`.

Looking at the docs for `install(... COMPONENT)`, I don't quite understand what it does either.